# Sub Query On Joined Table

Tags: sql, subquery

I need a little help with a query I am writing. I have broken it down to its most simple form.
An example of my table structure is shown below (I have altered it for clarity):

```
Users
    UserId int -- PK Identity
    Username    varchar(30)

DirectReports
    DirectReportId  int -- PK Identity
    UserId int -- FK to Users.UserId
    ManagerId -- FK to Users.UserId

Documents
    DocumentId int -- PK Identity
    DocumentOwner int -- FK to Users.UserId
    DocumentName varchar(30)
    CreatedBy int -- FK to Users.UserId
    CreatedDate datetime
```

What I need to do, is allow users who have created a document to be able to see their own document.
So I use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsersDocuments
    @UserId         INT = null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select * from Documents D
    Where D.CreatedBy = ISNULL(@UserId, D.CreatedBy)
END
```

Which returns all documents created by a specific user.

However the business rules of the model, also dictate that another user may create a document on behalf of a user. So a user needs visibility of all records created by themselves, and all documents which they have ownership of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsersDocuments
    @UserId         INT = null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select * from Documents D
    Where D.CreatedBy = ISNULL(@UserId, D.CreatedBy)
    OR D.DocumentOwner = ISNULL(@UserId, D.DocumentOwner)
END
```

All works well. However, I have just been informed, that all direct reports of a user should have visibility of both documents created by a User, and documents a User has ownership of.

Given the example table structure I have defined, how would I express this in terms of a query?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from Documents D 
Where D.CreatedBy = ISNULL(@UserId, D.CreatedBy) 
    OR D.DocumentOwner = ISNULL(@UserId, D.DocumentOwner)  
    OR D.DocumentOwner = ( select ManagerID from DirectReports where @UserId = UserID)
```